# Can i convert a textured mesh to a pointcloud for rendering purpose?

Tags: rendering, mesh, geometry-nodes

I was wondering if there is any way of converting a 3d mesh model with textures into a point cloud that could be rendered as a png? Im a blender begginer so I have been trying it with geometry nodes ( mesh to points and distribute points on faces ) but the result isnt visible in material preview or rendered mode even when i aplly the material node. I have also been trying to import a textured mesh into CloudCompare but it keeps failing to load the textures.
[image: this is the result im going for]